# How to stop a user entering white spaces into a cell in an Excel file created with EPPlus

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, epplus

Sorry for the title what stack overflow considers subjective is ridiculous.

I want add validation to an excel file downloaded from my application using EPPlus. I need the Validation to stop the user entering white spaces into a column. I have basic validation checking length already on the column and I need to add extra validation to the column to check for white spaces. I have messed around with adding custom and ended up trying something like this

```
var colValidation = codeSheet.DataValidations.AddCustomValidation("A:A");
codeValidation.Formula.ExcelFormula = "=ISERR(FIND(' ',A:A))";
```

But I had no luck. Is there a way of doing this using RegEx or has anyone managed to do this?

**UPDATE: Latest Code**

```
        var codeValidation = codeSheet.DataValidations.AddCustomValidation("A:A");
        codeValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        codeValidation.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.stop;
        codeValidation.ErrorTitle = "An invalid value was entered";
        codeValidation.Error = "Code must be Unique, between 1 and 8 digits in length and alphanumeric";
        codeValidation.Formula.ExcelFormula = "=ISERR(FIND(\" \",A:A))";
        //codeValidation.Formula.ExcelFormula = "=ISERR(FIND(\" \"))";
```

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: Is the information be entered from the excel sheet? Or from your own? as a general rule, it is usually much easier (and way safer) to allow the data you want instead of trying to prevent everything else.

Comment: Yes the user can enter the information from the Excel Sheet, I have checks on the application side so any bad data won't be processed, but from a usability side I want to inform the user if they have entered bad data before they try to upload the excel back to the applicataion

Answer (score 1):

Chang the single quote to double quote since it's the string 'space' your searching for.  Remember to escape the double quote with a backslash for EPPLUS.

```
"=ISERR(FIND(\" \",A:A))";
```

---

To validate that the user enters a alphanumeric string between 1 and 8 characters in length and has no spaces anywhere in the string, use this formula instead:  (As written it Validates Cell A1 only)

```
"=(LEN(A1)<9)*((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,\" \",\"\")))=0)"
```

---

**EDIT**

To apply the test to the whole column you need to enter the formula as an array formula.  For example, if your applying this to column A, write your equation for A1 and use an array formula.  If you were to enter this manually in excel you would hold CTRL+SHIFT and then hit enter when typing the formula.

To enter an array formula programatically you need to use `FormulaArray` instead of `ExcelFormula`

`codeValidation` is already pointing to the whole column so all you need is this:

```
codeValidation.Formula.FormulaArray = "=ISERROR(FIND(\" \",A1)=FALSE)";
```

or

```
codeValidation.Formula.FormulaArray = "=(LEN(A1)<9)*((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,\" \",\"\")))=0)";
```

This is **untested** using EPPLUS

Comment: Hi I have tried this it s still not working I can download the excel and there appears to be no errors but if I add new codes it won't stop me adding in spaces. I tested it by setting the cell to A3 specifically incase it was something to do with the column not been selected properly

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I spent a while playing with Excel and =ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)=FALSE) works for the cell A1 also. I've spotted 2 problems that I'm having the first is that my data validations aren't getting added to the Excel and the second is that the formulas are breaking if you try to do the check over an entire column with A:A

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. I think I'm going to have to leave this. From what I'm reading about excel I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible, the reason I'm thinking this is because the cell needs to be specified in each formula. I'm not sure that EPPlus is able to handle changing the Formula String. The Formulas are breaking if I specify a range and EPPlus isn't applying them the same way if you used CTRL+SHIFT.